# Still need help: How to tweak an action/animation without affecting other actions?

Tags: animation, modifiers, armature, bones, transforms

Im new at Blender and trying to fix/tweak some bones without affecting other actions or animations

This needs to be fixed, the fingers are twisted because of retargeting fail:

[image]

But when I do for example this with animation 1 (fighting), it works like it should:

[image]

BUT This happens to other animations(or actions) (e.g. holding gun):

[image]

So how do I edit only the animation 1 (Action) bones/rigs without it affecting to other animations at Action Editor?

The animations are from motion capture data and I only need to tweak some bones, like fingers in this case.

Comment: Please include your images directly in your question not by posting external links. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Hi, my account is so new its not possible.

Comment: Ok. It's impossible to say what's going on just from those images. Can you upload the Blend file so that someone can have a look to see what's happening? https://blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: Sorry, I explained more whats happening

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `NLA editor` to perform this. I have 2 actions one for `location` and another for `rotation`. I have combined it using `NLA editor`.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer, I only find NLA related tutorials when I look for Action editor related stuff. It works well for whole action, but it affects other actions too. https://imgur.com/zr3pCvB, also what that "0" means in name of most of the actions?

Comment: 0 means that these actions are not used yet. It comes to every field of Blender like `material` and `nodes`. Here is an example: https://imgur.com/a/R4Asn0H

Comment: Okay, but what it means in Action Editor, used where?

Comment: It means that currently those animations or actions are not used to any rig or object.

Comment: Im confused, both action/animations works fine with or without 0

Comment: It does not do anything it just tells you that it is not used yet. If you close your blender the 0-named animations will be removed.

Comment: Apparently. So I should use Fake user option always in this case?

Comment: yes, if you don't want to lose your animations.

Comment: Thanks for help, didnt really solve main problem but now I know better

Comment: `NLA Editor` is the solution for this case.

Comment: I try to learn it next, but I think I dont need advanced animation stuff as I use motion capture data and only need to tweak some bones (like those finger at first image)